# How to check select statement choice before submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select area for the user:

```
<select class="span12" placeholder="Enquiry Type" name="enquiry" id="enquiry">
 <option value='' selected></option>
 <option value='cv'>Submit CV</option>
 <option value='vacancy'>Submit Vacancy</option>
</select>
```

I have a hidden field in the form which allows the user to upload their cv. I now need it so that if the user selects submit cv, the field will display itself.

```
<input type="file" name="cv" accept="application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" style="display:none;">
```

I know that i would be able to check the user input of the select using an on click function. Is there a way of doing it without that (there and then)? And then if that option is selected, display the hidden file upload.

Comment: U need that If user select "CV" then fileUpload controller should be shown and in any else condition it should be hidden .... M i Right ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#enquiry').on('change', function(e) {
       if($(this).val() === "cv") {
          $('input[name="cv"]').show();
       }
 });
```

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/dL8evt33/

:)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by hooking to the `change` event of the `select` and checking the selected value. You can then use `toggle()` to hide or show the `input` as needed. Try this:

```
$('#enquiry').change(function() {
    $('input[type="file"]').toggle($(this).val() == 'cv');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/horjb31w/)

Comment: Always use `on(` to bind evets, `change, click, ...` are helper methods that internally calls `on()`

Comment: Why? The shortcuts are perfectly valid to use. Internally it is exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, they are valid, but directly using `on` saves one function call and improves performance slightly

Comment: Check jQuery source on [GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/alias.js#L14)

Answer (score 0):

remove `display: none;` first now do write this code.

```
$("[id$=fileupload]").hide();

if("[id$=enquiry]").val('cv')
{
    $("[id$=fileupload]").show();
}
else
{
    $("[id$=fileupload]").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On change event you can display the input type file using its id. Give 'file' as id to hidden field -

```
$('#enquiry').on('change', function() {
    if("cv" == this.value){
    jQuery("#file").show(); // or jQuery("#file").toggle();
    }
});
```